# High tech crime

Tags: science-fiction, crime

For a near-future cyberpunk story, what inventive crimes using high tech (not including hacking, ransomware, etc, as these already are too commonplace) already exist today? One thing that comes to my mind is the use of drones for smuggling and monitoring. Another thing that comes to my mind is some guys who were using photos from high zoom / high resolution cameras to duplicate keys.
Any other examples?

Answer (score 1):

Murder by AI drone. Suppose deliveries of packages are made by drones, and these are marked by standard delivery services. Somebody could make a drone that looks exactly like one of the commercial drones, but the "package" to be delivered actually contains a poison dart (e.g. cyanide, and the drone has an AI primed to recognize a particular person.

Nobody suspects the drone of doing anything but a delivery to somewhere, but it is actually searching for its target, and when it finds the target it shoots them with the dart, and moves on.

Alternatively it could explode, shoot a gun, and perhaps even destroy itself to ensure it cannot be traced, but these might harm other people; the poison or disease might be enough.

Speaking of which, AI might be used to create custom toxins. Get a copy of the victim's DNA, and have an AI devise a poison that only works on that one person, or perhaps engineer a virus or bacterium that can only interact with that person's DNA. It can be released into a ventilation system, or open air, and won't bother anybody except that one individual, which it will give an incurable, fatal disease.

How about AI or drone corporate espionage?

How about micro drones, that look like gnats? Or, like octopi, can convincingly change their coloring and texture to fit into a background; the drone is an inch long, but blends in perfectly with the wallpaper or ceiling, or a painting on the wall.

AI is an exponential arms race, we are already using AI to accelerate the development of faster AI.

There will always be some people that aren't yet aware of what was developed last month, and the criminals that make breakthroughs aren't going to publicize those breakthroughs, except by using them to commit crimes and big crimes.

Answer (score 0):

Bio-ransom: infect someone with an engineered virus that progressively re-writes their DNA, shutting down their body’s production of key proteins.  The infected have to pay a ransom to get a counter virus that halts the original virus and reverses its effects

Identity Forgery: creating fake people that get remote jobs and get paychecks and have fake accidents and sue manufacturers and claim benefits Think Sock-Puppet write large. But they’d be used by cyber-grifters who’d profit by the arbitrage of shipping the work to low cost regions,  The fake people have whole careers, moving from job to job, accruing benefits.  They’d also be a way to get past a corporation’s firewills and steal information

Hijacking self-driving freight trucks.  Between the time the truck leaves the dock or warehouse loaded with goods, they breech its security then sell then sell the goods to unsuspecting vendors, delivering them right to their door.

Eaves dropping and recording private virtual reality sessions and using the content to blackmail someone.  Think discussions between your lawyer or therapist or fantasies played out in VR.

Cyber-neural programming:  think inception but on a more limbic level where cyber-space is used to imprint desires on the human limbic system on a subliminal level